# How to pass an associative array to a PHP file using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have created an associative array like this

```
HeaderArray["BillNo"] = ["BillNo", BillNo];
HeaderArray["CustomerId"] = ["CustomerId", CusId];
HeaderArray["Date"] = ["CustomerId", "03/11/1995"];
```

Now I am trying to pass this array to a PHP file.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Resource/Start.php',
    data: { HeaderDetails: HeaderArray },
    success: function (Data) {                                      
        console.log(Data);                          
    },
});
```

php file

```
if (!isset($_POST['HeaderDetails'])) {
    echo 'HeaderDetails is not set';

} else {
    echo 'HeaderDetails Set';
}
```

In the console I always get the output as `HeaderDetails not set`.

Comment: @u_mulder that does nt work

Comment: Doesn't work __how__?

Comment: I get undefined Index Error @u_mulder

Comment: Google for mdn xhr example. Then google for php json encode. ;) Good luck. Oh, and really try Google for ubiquitous stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
$.post({
           url:'Resource/Start.php',
           data:{HeaderDetails:JSON.stringify(dataStringHeaderArray)
       }.done(function (Data){                                        
             console.log(Data);                                  
       });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the thing you're missing is the ajax dataType(text,json,xml) in our case we use text as print_r($_POST) will return an array which is not json formated.
And secondly no declaration for HeaderArray which will be in this case of type object. so,

Try with:

```
<form method="POST">
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("form").submit(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var HeaderArray = {};
                HeaderArray["BillNo"] = ["BillNo", "12"];
                HeaderArray["CustomerId"] = ["CustomerId", "12"];
                HeaderArray["Date"] = ["CustomerId", "03/11/1995"];
                $.ajax({
                    url:"backend/yourHandler.php",
                    type:"POST",
                    dataType:"text",
                    data:{ HeaderArray : HeaderArray },
                    success:function(result){

                        console.log(result);
                    },
                    error:function(err,status,xhr){
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });
                return false;

            });
        });
    </script>
```

// backend/yourHandler.php

```
<?PHP print_r($_POST); ?>
```